# Problems with clickable object unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have been making this 2D game in Unity and it has buttons on the left all the time. The buttons are actually objects with no text and a sprite, which are supposed to stay on one place and activate a function on click (the function works).

I have tried using this simple script, but it appears to not be working, even after adding hitboxes/rigibodies to the object:
{
    public int TerraformClick;

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1) == true)
        {
            float TerraformClick = 1;
            print("Changed TerraformClick");
        }
}
```

So I just want to ask what the errors are, if there are some (none popped out)

Comment: Button 1 is 'secondary button' (typically right click). Button 0 is the normal left click. Does this fix it?

Comment: First of all: what ryeMoss said, also: do you want to press the objects substituting buttons or do you want it to happen everytime you hit the left mouse button?

Comment: so the other buttons you are talking about are `UI.Button` or `UI.Image` components? Maybe you can checkout [OnMouseDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html)

Comment: This code detects when the mouse button is pressed with no regards to *where* the mouse is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code would detect if you clicked a specific object.

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
     Destroy (this.gameObject);
}
```

The object would need a rigidbody and a collider of some sort.